# Adding months using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Currently I have a below record in a file.

```
ABC,XYZ,123,Sep-2018
```

Looking for a command in linux which will add months and give the output. For example If I want to add 3 months. Expected output is:

```
ABC,XYZ,123,Dec-2018
```

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: you have the file with only one record?

Comment: will have multiple records.

Comment: @Programmer, you should specify the rules of detecting such record. What if there another record `aaa - Feb-2018, bbbb` ? The one should know the clear format of the searched record

Comment: The format with multiple records is clear. All records will be in the same format. The 4th column in the comma separated is the one which I want to convert.

Comment: if you add one month on a field `Dec-2018`, are you expecting `Jan-2019`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

```
date -d "1-$(echo "ABC,XYZ,123,Sep-2018" | awk -F ","  '{ print $4 }')+3 months" "+%b-%Y"
```

(Careful, that code continues past the edge of the box.)

Shows you how to get it working. Just replace the `echo` with a shell variable as you loop through the dates.

Basically, you use `awk` to grab just the date portion, add a `1-` to the front to turn it into a real date then use the `date` command to do the math and then tell it to give you just the month abbreviation and year.

The line above gives just the date portion. The first part can be found using:

```
stub=`echo "ABC,XYZ,123,Dec-2018" | awk -F ","  '{ printf("%s,%s,%s,",$1,$2,$3) }'`
```

Comment: @Programmer - I've added a line showing how to get the stub.

Comment: @TonyWilliams I have worked with the above command and it has helped me to get the required results. Thanks for the same :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use external `date` or (g)awk's datetime related function to do it. However you have to prepare the string to parse. Here is another way to do the job:

First prepare an index file, we name it `month.txt`:

```
Jan
Feb
......
...
Nov
Dec
```

Then run this:

```
awk -F'-|,' -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{m[NR]=$1;a[$1]=NR;next}
    {i=a[$4]; if(i==12){i=1;++$5}else i++
    $4=m[i]"-"$5;NF--}7' month.txt file
```

With this example file:

```
ABC,XYZ,123,Jan-2018
ABC,XYZ,123,Nov-2018
ABC,XYZ,123,Dec-2018
```

You will get:

```
ABC,XYZ,123,Feb-2018
ABC,XYZ,123,Dec-2018
ABC,XYZ,123,Jan-2019
```

### update

Oh, I didn't notice that you want to add 3 months. Here is the updated codes for it:

```
 awk -F'-|,' -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{m[NR]=$1;a[$1]=NR;next}
    {i=a[$4]+3; if(i>12){i=i-12;++$5}
    $4=m[i]"-"$5;NF--}7' month.txt file
```

Now with the same input, you get:

```
ABC,XYZ,123,Apr-2018
ABC,XYZ,123,Feb-2019
ABC,XYZ,123,Mar-2019
```